# Variable passed to directive not resolving

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element that is passing a scope variable to a directive but instead of getting the value that I am expecting inside of the directive, I am getting a string of the variable name.

```
myApp.directive('slide', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

    function animate(slide) {
        if (slide) {
            $(element).slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $(element).slideUp(300);
        }
    };

    // Animate based on initial value
    animate(scope.$eval(attrs.slide));

    // Animate on scope change
    scope.$watch(attrs.slide, function (newVal) {
        animate(newVal);
    });

    };
});

<ul slide="option.expanded"></ul>
```

The console shows `intial  option.expanded`. Yet when `scope.$watch` fires the value is as it should be (a boolean). The variable is initially set in the view's controller when it starts.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've tried many different things but all to no avail.

Comment: I see `attrs.slide` and `attrs.slideSubMenu`. Are those supposed to be different? Also, if you're setting the value in the controller you could access it in the directive with scope: `scope.slide`

Comment: Did you read directive documentation? what happens when you do `scope.eval(attrs.slide)`. You are just reading the attribute value as is. Instead you need to read the value of the model assigned to it.

Comment: @Austin sorry that was a typo

Comment: @PSL yes and I think a post link function is best for this, which is what I find that I am using. Can you please correct me if I'm mistaken?

Comment: @PSL I actually just tried that right before you mentioned it, and it worked. The only problem now is element does not seem to be available for use in a jQuery selector. Thanks so much for that suggestion. Do you think I am using the wrong kind of function in this directive?

Comment: @ChrisB which element is not available for selection. What are you doing inside the directive? Can you elaborate your example code

Comment: @PSL The element provided by angular to the directive's function via the arguments. I have added more code, sorry for the short example

Comment: btw you dont need to do `$(element)` you  could just do `element`. It works for me.. http://plnkr.co/edit/eCdoVX5I6ENyexB0yNlr?p=preview

Comment: @PSL Thanks for the tips. scope.$eval solved my first problem, and I had a CSS rule permanently hiding the element so that was the cause of the jQuery not working. so scope.$eval answers this question's original question. I'm good to go now, thanks for your help!!

Comment: @ChrisB You are welcome... Guess you had `!important` in your rule.?

Comment: Didn't use important, but for some reason it was overriding what jQuery was trying to do. odd indeed. I get why would think I used !important. It is fishy

Comment: @ChrisB :) anyways good that you have it resolved.. All the best!!